# How do we allocate a 2-D array using One malloc statement

Tags: c

I have been asked in an interview how do i allocate a 2-D array and below was my solution to it.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int **array;
array = malloc(nrows * sizeof(int *));

for(i = 0; i < nrows; i++)
{
    array[i] = malloc(ncolumns * sizeof(int));
    if(array[i] == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "out of memory\n");
        exit or return
    }
}
```

I thought I had done a good job but then he asked me to do it using one `malloc()` statement not two. I don't have any idea how to achieve it.

Can anyone suggest me some idea to do it in single `malloc()`?

Comment: Actually this is making (nrows + 1) malloc calls.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Correctly allocating multi-dimensional arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays).

Comment: Warning: many of the answers posted here are harmful. Read the answers by John Bode and chux, ignore the rest.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Just compute the total amount of memory needed for both `nrows` row-pointers, and the actual data, add it all up, and do a single call:

```
int **array = malloc(nrows * sizeof *array + (nrows * (ncolumns * sizeof **array));
```

If you think this looks too complex, you can split it up and make it a bit self-documenting by naming the different terms of the size expression:

```
int **array; /* Declare this first so we can use it with sizeof. */
const size_t row_pointers_bytes = nrows * sizeof *array;
const size_t row_elements_bytes = ncolumns * sizeof **array;
array = malloc(row_pointers_bytes + nrows * row_elements_bytes);
```

You then need to go through and initialize the row pointers so that each row's pointer points at the first element for that particular row:

```
size_t i;
int * const data = array + nrows;
for(i = 0; i < nrows; i++)
  array[i] = data + i * ncolumns;
```

Note that the resulting structure is subtly different from what you get if you do e.g. `int array[nrows][ncolumns]`, because we have explicit row pointers, meaning that for an array allocated like this, there's no real requirement that all rows have the same number of columns.

It also means that an access like `array[2][3]` does something distinct from a similar-looking access into an actual 2d array. In this case, the innermost access happens first, and `array[2]` reads out a pointer from the 3rd element in `array`. That pointer is then treatet as the base of a (column) array, into which we index to get the fourth element.

In contrast, for something like

```
int array2[4][3];
```

which is a "packed" proper 2d array taking up just 12 integers' worth of space, an access like `array[3][2]` simply breaks down to adding an offset to the base address to get at the element.

Comment: @Unwind can i have pictorial view of memory for this solution it helpes in greated details to understand this code.

Comment: @AmitSinghTomar: I don't think I can represent this in ASCII clearly, and don't have the time to draw something in a real graphics program at the moment, sorry. Perhaps someone can step in? :)

Comment: Thanks any way @unwind ,I got an idea how's things are working in memory for your code.

Comment: @unwind, when you allocate each row with malloc(), each row could also be different length.

Comment: @AmigableClarkKant: Yes of course ... I didn't compare against that, I compared against a simple pure C 2D array such as `int array[nrows][ncols]`.

Comment: @unwind,is not it take more bytes of allocation then required, my point is if we have int a[2][2] it would take 16 bytes in memory(assuming int size of 4 byte) but with dynamic allocation it is taking 24 byte,why?

Comment: @AmitSinghTomar It takes more memory since you have a pointer for each row, which is necessary to "hide" the fact that the width of the array is dynamic. It allows double indexing like `array[i][j]` by making `array[i]` be a valid pointer at that row's data.

Comment: What is the use of "int *data = array + nrows;" ? Please explain.

Comment: @UdbhavKalra The use should be clear from the code; it's to just make the address of the first element more easily accessible and remove that constant calculation from the loop. I think it helps with clarity.

Comment: So, it means that some number of blocks (=number of rows) will be there at the starting location of the array, just after that, there will be some blocks (=no of rows again which is also divided into number of blocks (=number of columns) ). Please correct me if I am wrong. Thanks.

Comment: One question: the row `int * const data = array + nrows;` generates a warning for me: `incompatible pointer types initializing 'int *const' with an expression of type 'int **'; dereference with *`. Is this to be ignored?

Otherwise thx for a great answer.

Comment: `int **array = malloc(nrows * sizeof *array + (nrows * (ncolumns * sizeof **array));` is not guaranteed to work.  For example, if pointers are 4 bytes and the data elements require 8-byte alignment, a 3xN array would place data elements on a 4-byte alignment.

Comment: Is there any benefit to using just one malloc call instead of multiple malloc calls? Does it guarantee tighter packing?

Comment: @OS2 It's faster by necessity (heap allocation is an expensive operation), and it minimizes per-allocation overhead. I do believe it can (and very often will) lead to tighter layout in memory, yes, since new allocations are aligned to fit any data and that allocation might be more wasteful than what is needed for the actual arrays here.

Comment: Is it possible to avoid the warning @Sahand mentions without casting `array + nrows` to `(int *)`

Comment: This approach fails with `int * const data = array + nrows;` in the rare case of `int` alignment needs exceeding those of `int *`.  Can be repaired with additional code (e.g, a `union`) to account for the needed padding.  IOWs, for `int` this very likely works, yet perhaps not for a wide type with greater than pointer alignment needs like `double`.

Answer (score 16):

```
int **array = malloc (nrows * sizeof(int *) + (nrows * (ncolumns * sizeof(int)));
```

This works because in C, arrays are just all the elements one after another as a bunch of bytes. There is no metadata or anything. malloc() does not know whether it is allocating for use as chars, ints or lines in an array.

Then, you have to initialize:

```
int *offs = &array[nrows]; /*  same as int *offs = array + nrows; */
for (i = 0; i < nrows; i++, offs += ncolumns) {
    array[i] = offs;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Amigable for your solution but I don't understand where int *offs = &arr[nrows] come from,I mean purpose of this line and where we have declared &arr[nrows] ??

Comment: The added setup code looks wrong, the row stride is 1, should be ncolumns.

Comment: int* data = array + nrows; in unwinds answer is the same as int* offs = &array[nrows]; @AmitSinghTomar

Comment: Thanks @AmigableClarkKant got your point a[i]=*(a+i) ,something like this

Comment: Could you please explain the second part ?

Comment: @UdbhavKalra, could you please elaborate your question?

Comment: Yes, thanks for replying. I would like to ask about the initialization part where &array[nrows] is mentioned. As, (nrows) is there, not (nrows-1), so, it would point to the last row + (size of 1 more row). I doubt whether I am right here or not but please clarify. And, if it points @ the end. So, shouldn't it be offs -= ncolumns. I know that I misinterpreted it. So, please explain that part. Thanks again.

Comment: @UdbhavKalra, hmmm... not sure. Could it be that you need to consider that position 0 is the first position in the array?

Comment: But, how could the initialization of *offset = &array[nrows] would help ? I don't know what's going on

Comment: @UdbhavKalra I think I made a mistake. I think it should be `int* offs = array;`

Answer (score 11):

Here's another approach.

If you know the number of columns at compile time, you can do something like this:

```
#define COLS ... // integer value > 0
...
size_t rows;
int (*arr)[COLS];
...              // get number of rows
arr = malloc(sizeof *arr * rows);
if (arr)
{
  size_t i, j;
  for (i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
      arr[i][j] = ...;
}
```

If you're working in C99, you can use a pointer to a VLA:

```
size_t rows, cols;
...               // get rows and cols
int (*arr)[cols] = malloc(sizeof *arr * rows);
if (arr)
{
  size_t i, j;
  for (i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < cols; j++)
      arr[i][j] = ...;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

> How do we allocate a 2-D array using One malloc statement (?)

No answers, so far, allocate memory for a true 2D array.

`int **array` is a [pointer to pointer to int](https://cdecl.org/?q=int+**Array).  `array` is not a pointer to a 2D array.

`int a[2][3]` is an example of a true 2D array or [array 2 of array 3 of int](https://cdecl.org/?q=int+A%5B2%5D%5B3%5D)

---

To allocate memory for a true 2D array, with C99, use `malloc()` and save to a pointer to a [variable-length array (VLA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array)

```
// Simply allocate and initialize in one line of code
int (*c)[nrows][ncolumns] = malloc(sizeof *c);

if (c == NULL) {
  fprintf(stderr, "out of memory\n");
  return;
} 
// Use c
(*c)[1][2] = rand();
...
free(c);
```

Without VLA support, if the dimensions are constants, code can use

```
#define NROW 4
#define NCOL 5
int (*d)[NROW][NCOL] = malloc(sizeof *d);
```

Comment: Wow, that's trippy.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this with (bit ugly with all the casting though):

```
int** array;
size_t pitch, ptrs, i;   
char* base; 
pitch = rows * sizeof(int);
ptrs = sizeof(int*) * rows;
array = (int**)malloc((columns * pitch) + ptrs);
base = (char*)array + ptrs;
for(i = 0; i < rows; i++)
{
    array[i] = (int*)(base + (pitch * i));
}
```

Comment: Clunky code - see @Amigable's answer for a more elegant and readable solution

Comment: @PaulR: when I posted my answer he hadn't updated his yet, I prefer unwind's answer though

Comment: @Necrolis, I am probably damaged from trying to optimize code on 80s computers. :-)  Back then, multiply inside loops were best avoided.

Comment: Both Amigable's and @unwind's are good, and are very similar - they are simple, readable and importantly they avoid unnecessary casts

Comment: @PaulR, actually, I usually do like how unwind uses sizeof(variable) instead of sizeof(type), but in this case I wanted my answer to be as similar to the original code as possible, so the OP can more easily understand the answer. I couldn't help but promulgate my indenting style though, it's probably hard coded in my brain... :-)

Comment: @PaulR: yeah, casts are a problem, my scaring from working with Direct3D and its memory region locking :)

Comment: Note that "array + ptrs" may not be appropriately aligned for the element type (it's unlikely to be a problem for int, but still not guaranteed to work by the C standard - more likely to be an issue for e.g. double) - you will need to round ptrs up to the next sizeof(element type).

Comment: @Random832: everything is done using a multiple of `sizeof(int)`, the only alignment problems would come from `malloc` (which I doubt).

Comment: @Necrolis My point was, `sizeof(int *)` (therefore `sizeof(int*) * rows`) may not be a multiple of `sizeof(int)`. It is, on most common platforms, but that's not guaranteed. Like I said, it's more likely to be an issue for other types like double.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a fan of this "array of pointers to array" to solve the multi dimension array paradigm. Always favored a single dimension array, at access the element with array[ row * cols + col]? No problems encapsulating everything in a class, and implementing a 'at' method.

If you insist on accessing the members of the array with this notation: Matrix[i][j], you can do a little C++ magic. @John solution tries to do it this way, but he requires the number of column to be known at compile time. With some C++ and overriding the operator[], you can get this completely:

```
class Row
{
private:
    int* _p;

public:
    Row( int* p )                   { _p = p; }
    int& operator[](int col)        { return _p[col]; }
};


class Matrix
{
private:
    int* _p;
    int _cols;

public:
    Matrix( int rows, int cols )  { _cols=cols; _p = (int*)malloc(rows*cols ); }
    Row operator[](int row)       { return _p + row*_cols; }
};
```

So now, you can use the Matrix object, for example to create a multiplication table:

```
Matrix mtrx(rows, cols);
for( i=0; i<rows; ++i ) {
    for( j=0; j<rows; ++j ) {
        mtrx[i][j] = i*j;
    }
}
```

You should now that the optimizer is doing the right thing and there is no call function or any other kind of overhead. No constructor is called. As long as you don't move the Matrix between function, even the _cols variable isn't created. The statement *mtrx[i][j]* basically does mtrx[i*cols+j].

Comment: This question never had the C++ tags.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done as follows:

```
#define NUM_ROWS 10
#define NUM_COLS 10

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char (*p)[NUM_COLS] = NULL;
    p = malloc(NUM_ROWS * NUM_COLS);
    memset(p, 81, NUM_ROWS * NUM_COLS);
    p[2][3] = 'a';
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_ROWS; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < NUM_COLS; j++) {
            printf("%c\t", p[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
} // end of main
```

Answer (score -2):

You can allocate `(row*column) * sizeof(int)` bytes of memory using malloc.
Here is a code snippet to demonstrate.

```
int row = 3, col = 4;
int *arr = (int *)malloc(row * col * sizeof(int));

int i, j, count = 0;
for (i = 0; i <  r; i++)
  for (j = 0; j < c; j++)
     *(arr + i*col + j) = ++count; //row major memory layout

for (i = 0; i <  r; i++)
  for (j = 0; j < c; j++)
     printf("%d ", *(arr + i*col + j));
```

Comment: Getting segmentation fault with this approach