# Freeing the memory - two dimensional array

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010

I use Visual C++ 2010 and I'm trying to use free() with two dimensional array:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define SIZE 8


int main(){

    int **matrix = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int*)*SIZE);
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<SIZE; i++){
        matrix[i] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*SIZE);
    }
    for(i=0; i<SIZE; i++){
        free(matrix[i]);
    }
    free(matrix);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Am I doing this right?

Regards.

Comment: So far, it looks right, are you geting crash or nasty effects ?..

Comment: Have you compiled and tried to run it? Did that work?

Comment: Don't cast the return value of `malloc`...

Comment: it works, but I'm not sure about it...

Comment: looks ok, I'd probably just allocate it in one malloc if you just want a matrix of ints.

Comment: @bash.d There are good arguments for and against casting malloc. Read about them and you will realize stating *Don't cast the return value of malloc* is futile.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically it should be right.

Btw you don't need to call `malloc` for each row of the 2d array you are trying to allocate (unless you have specific reasons to do that).

You can use just one `malloc` and one `free`:

```
malloc(sizeof(int*)*ROW_NUM * COL_NUM);
```

Using a single call to `malloc` has also the benefits to allocate continuosly in memory the elements of your matrix.

Comment: why the downvote? The answer is right. At least give some reasons

Comment: sometimes you just get them for no reason.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it. Although you can and probably should (for efficiency purposes) do just one malloc and one free as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8740195/how-do-we-allocate-a-2-d-array-using-one-malloc-statement)

If you don't need to be in C explicitly, it might be worth taking a look at vectors to handle the memory for you.