# Trying to create a 2D array at whose size is only known at runtime in c+

Tags: c++, arrays, malloc

I'm trying to create a 2D array in c++ whose size is only known at runtime.

I tried doing the following:

```
std::ifstream myFile;
myFile.open("input.txt",std::ios::in);
int num_cols;
myFile >> num_cols;
int num_rows = 10;

int *HArray;
HArray = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int)*num_cols*num_rows);
```

But when I try this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < num_rows; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < num_cols; j++) {
        HArray[i][j] = i*j + 34*j;
    }
}
```

I get the following error during compilation:

---

> Error 2   error C2109: subscript requires array or pointer type

---

**How do I allocate the memory for HArray such that I can use the indices [i][j] to access and assign values to the array?**

I tried following @Uri's answer available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8740195/how-do-we-allocate-a-2-d-array-using-one-malloc-statement), but the program immediately crashes, and I didn't really understand what was going on either.

**EDIT:**

I decided to use the following

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> HArray(num_rows, std::vector<int>(num_cols));
```

Comment: I *highly* recommend you read a good C++ book. Learning C++ by trial and error or from random snippets from the web will end poorly, trust me.

Comment: do you know the number of rows?

Comment: @BaummitAugen but it's not random snippets, it's a good stackoverflow answer...

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre It's a random snippet if you don't understand what's going on.

Comment: @Veridian you've got a 1D array here. If you really want a 2D array, [edit] your post and show us what you tried and try to figure out why it crashes.

Comment: @BaummitAugen I was being helf-sarcastic BTW. I think that the OP has adapted the answer and failed doing so. Now he has to edit his post to show his other attempt. Yes, it should use `new` or even better: `std::vector`

Comment: `std::vector<std::vector<int>> v(num_rows, std::vector<int>(num_cols));` might solve your issue.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Alright. My first comment still very much applies here. :)

Comment: @Jarod42, if he's doing this for a course or something -- which I would guess he is because this is a basic problem -- he might be required to use arrays instead of vectors. OP, just some general guiding advice, the definition of a 2D Array is an array-of-arrays. Go from there.

Comment: @Veridian I don't think Spencer was condescending. We have lots of questions where the instructions of the teacher was "not to use vectors" (yes, it kills the fun :))

Comment: @Veridian: [Demo](https://ideone.com/lDzXjE).

Comment: @Veridian - [Already answered here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21943621/how-to-create-a-contiguous-2d-array-in-c/21944048#21944048)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: that's for C. For C++ answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/936687/how-do-i-declare-a-2d-array-in-c-using-new

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre That's actually C++ as it templatizes the data type of the 2D array.  I'm assuming the OP is stuck using dynamic allocation and can't use `std::vector`.

Comment: I'm not stuck using anything. I just didn't realize vector was the way to go. Vector worked for me, so thanks to @Jarod42. But if I use 'new', then I have to use 'delete'. When vector, I don't have to do that though, right?

Comment: Allocate with malloc(N  * M *sizeof(double))> Access with array[y*M] = x;

Comment: @Veridian `vector` deallocates its memory when it goes out of scope. so no need to. That's one of the reasons C++ is better than C. You should use C++ for vectors & strings only, even if you don't use classes.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, thanks for the backup ;) I definitely was not intending to come off as condescending. I simply do not know the OP's experience level nor do I know the constraints (_e.g., cannot use vectors or something_). If this were for a class homework assignment, I wouldn't want to just explicitly give out the answer, because I personally think it is important for students to take the time to think critically, read documentation, and figure things out independently. As such, in the case of a student doing a homework assignment, I prefer to provide a hint rather than an answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>


int main()
{
    std::ifstream myFile;
    myFile.open("input.txt", std::ios::in);
    int num_cols;
    myFile >> num_cols;
    int num_rows = 10;


    int** HArray = new int*[num_rows];
    for (int i = 0; i < num_rows; ++i)
    {
        HArray[i] = new int[num_cols];
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create a 2D array in C++ starting from a double pointer

```
int     **  matrix;  
matrix = new int * [num_cols];
for (int i = 0; i < num_cols; i++){
    matrix[i] = new int [num_rows];
}
```

Comment: "double pointer" is misleading, it's a pointer to pointer to int, not a pointer to double.

Comment: Another issue is that if the matrix is not ragged (differing row sizes), this is about the worst way to create one using a loop (even though this seems to be the way that gets presented the most).  For a more efficient way of doing this, [see this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21943621/how-to-create-a-contiguous-2d-array-in-c/21944048#21944048)