# How can I dynamically allocate 2D-array in one allocate C

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, malloc, allocation

Can you help me figure out how to allocate a 2D-array in one allocate call?

I tried to do:

> int** arr = (int**)malloc(num * num * sizeof(int*));

But its doesn't work.

`num` is the rows and columns.

Comment: `int (*arr)[num] = malloc(sizeof(int[num][num]));`

Comment: That's not a 2D array and cannot point to one!

Comment: @WeatherVane: of course you can. It is just a different type.

Comment: @Olaf yes, I just tried the BLUEPIXY code, very good.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do we allocate a 2-D array using One malloc statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8740195/how-do-we-allocate-a-2-d-array-using-one-malloc-statement)

Comment: @WeatherVane: Oh, does MSVC finally support VLAs??

Comment: @Olaf, no, nor does it have to. I used `#define num 3` ;)

Comment: Yes, they never stated the were standard compliant.

Comment: @Olaf, come on, VLAs are now optional as you know. So MS held their breath and can now breathe out ...

Comment: @WeatherVane: Honi soit qui mal y pense ... I wounder if this is related to the influence of certain proprietary compiler manufacturers. All modern compilers do support C99, which had VLAs mandatory. Anyway, AFAIK, it does not support other **required** feature, too.

Comment: @Olaf you are repeating yourself. I have never supplied MSVC C code to customers, and I never will.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How can i to allocate dynamically array2D in 1 allocate C

Let us start with what is a 2D array:
Example of a [2D array or "array 3 of array 4 of int"](https://cdecl.org/?q=int+arr1%5B3%5D%5B4%5D%3B)

```
int arr1[3][4];
arr1[0][0] = this;
```

OP's code declares a [pointer to pointer to int](https://cdecl.org/?q=int+arr1%5B3%5D%5B4%5D%3B), not a 2D array nor a pointer to a 2D array.
BTW, the cast in not needed.

```
int** arr = (int**)malloc(num * num * sizeof(int*));
```

---

Code can allocate memory for a 2D array and return a pointer to that memory.  [pointer to array 5 of array 6 of int](https://cdecl.org/?q=int+arr1%5B3%5D%5B4%5D%3B)

```
 int (*arr2)[5][6] = malloc(sizeof *arr2);
 if (arr2 == NULL) return EXIT_FAILURE;
 (*arr2)[0][0] = this;
 return EXIT_SUCCESS;

 // or with Variable Length Arrays in C99 and optionally in C11
 int (*arr3)[num][num] = malloc(sizeof *arr3);
 (*arr3)[0][0] = that;
```

---

Alternatively code can allocate memory for a 1D array and return a pointer to that memory.  [pointer to array 8 of int](https://cdecl.org/?q=int+arr1%5B3%5D%5B4%5D%3B).  Sometimes this is often what one wants with with an "allocate 2D" array, really a pointer to a 1D array

```
 int (*arr4)[8] = malloc(sizeof *arr4 * 7);
 arr4[0][0] = this;

 // or
 int (*arr5)[num] = malloc(sizeof *arr5 * num);
 arr5[0][0] = that;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can allocate a 2D array in one of 2 ways.

### 1: Array of Pointers to Arrays

This would be:

```
int rows = 10; 
int cols = 10;
int **array = malloc(rows * sizeof(int*));
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    array[i] = malloc(cols * sizeof(int));
}
```

`array` will now point to a list of pointers each representing a row, and those pointers would point to the elements in the row. In this case, you can access the nth row and mth column with `array[n][m]`

### 2: Single Continuous Block

This is probably the method you wanted, where you could do it all in one allocation. This would require you to store the 2D array in a 1D representation.

```
int rows = 10; 
int cols = 10;
int *array = malloc(rows * cols * sizeof(int));
```

You can then store and retrieve the nth row and mth column with an offset: `array[(n * cols) + m]`

Comment: None of them are 2D arrays. And the first does not allocate in one run.

Answer (score 1):

Although I thought the meaning of a "2D-array of integers" is unambiguously something like `int arr[10][10]`, searching the web brought up interpretations like "using an array of pointers" or "using a pointer to a pointer" (cf, for example, [this post](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamically-allocate-2d-array-c/)). The remainder of this answer is based on a 2D-array of the form `int arr[r][c]`, where `r` denotes the number of rows and `c` the number of columns per row.

If variable length arrays are not supported, then at least `c` must be a const expression (i.e. known at compile time). `r`, in contrast, may be defined at runtime as well, such that at least the number of rows is "dynamic". A 2D-array can then be represented as an (probably incomplete) array of one-D-arrays:

```
#define COLS 3

void printArray(int array[][COLS], int rows) {
    for(int row=0; row<rows; row++) {
        for (int col=0; col<COLS; col++) {
            printf("%d ", array[row][col]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main() {

    typedef int oneD[COLS];

    int rows = 5;
    size_t myArray5RowsSize = rows*sizeof(oneD);
    oneD *myArray5Rows = malloc(myArray5RowsSize);
    memset(myArray5Rows,0,myArray5RowsSize);
    myArray5Rows[0][0] = 0;
    myArray5Rows[1][1] = 1;
    myArray5Rows[2][2] = 2;

    printArray(myArray5Rows, 5);

    return 0;
}
```