# Segmentation fault while trying to initialise a 2d array

Tags: arrays, c, segmentation-fault, dynamic-memory-allocation

I don't know what is wrong here, I get a seg fault when I try to run this code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
    int **alloc_grid(int width, int height)
    {
        int i, j;
        int **grid;
   
        if (width < 1 || height < 1)
            return (NULL);
   
        grid = malloc(sizeof(int) * (width * height));
        if (grid == NULL)
            return (NULL);
        for (i = 0; i < height; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < width; j++)
                grid[i][j] = 0;
        }
        return (grid);
    }
```

It's supposed to initialise the 2d array with 0.

Comment: I can't compile it: `error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant 2`. It does not look like a segmentation fault.

Comment: oh, I forgot to add that this is a function to initialise the array and not main, so it wont compile.

Comment: `grid[i][j]` does not work with `int **` as you suppose it. `grid[i]` is `int*` then `[j]` dereferences the uninitialized `int*`.

Comment: @273K oh, what should I do then?

Comment: First `grid = malloc(sizeof(int*) * height));`. Then allocate memory for each row.

Comment: Start from [How can I dynamically allocate 2D-array in one allocate C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43710298/how-can-i-dynamically-allocate-2d-array-in-one-allocate-c).

Comment: A more in-depth post: [Correctly allocating multi-dimensional arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that actually you allocated a one-dimensional array

```
grid = malloc(sizeof(int) * (width * height));
```

So dereferencing the pointer `grid` like

```
grid[i]
```

you are attempting to read the uninitialized allocated memory as a value of an address that results in undefined behavior.

You need either to allocate an array of pointers to arrays that will simulate a two-dimensional array like for example

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//...

grid = malloc(sizeof(int *) * height);

for ( int i = 0; i < height; i++ )
{
    grid[i] = malloc( sizeof( int ) * width );
}

for ( int i = 0; i < height; i++ )
{
    memset( grid[i], 0, sizeof( int ) * width );
}
```

Or you could allocate a one dimensional array as you already did but use only one subscript operator. In this case the pointer `grid` shall have the type `int *` and the function will be declared like

```
int * alloc_grid(int width, int height);
```

For example

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//...

int *grid;
//...
grid = malloc( sizeof(int) * width * height );
memset( grid, 0, sizeof( int ) * height * width );
```

Or instead of calling the function `memset` you could initially initialize the arrays by zero using `calloc` instead of `malloc` as for example

```
grid = malloc(sizeof(int *) * height);

for ( int i = 0; i < height; i++ )
{
    grid[i] = calloc( width, sizeof( int ) );
}
```

or

```
grid = calloc( width * height, sizeof(int) );
```

Answer (score 1):

A pointer to pointer cannot be used to point at anything but the first item in an array of pointers. It cannot be used to point at 2D arrays.

Also note that if you only intend to set everything to zero after calling `malloc`, you may as well use `calloc`, which is guaranteed to do just that.

The quick solution would look like:

```
void* alloc_grid (int width, int height)
{
    if (width < 1 || height < 1)
      return NULL;
    grid_t* g = calloc( 1, sizeof(int[width][height]) );
    return g;
}
```

Usage:

```
int (*grid)[height] = alloc_grid(width, height);
if(grid == NULL)
/* handle error */
...
grid[i][j] = something;
...
free(grid);
```

The only downside is that the `void*` drops all type safety. More intricate solutions involve wrapping the array inside a struct.