# Two dimension arrays and pointer representation

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

Three questions in 1.

1. If I have a 2-D array -

   ```
   int array_name[num_rows][num_columns]
   ```

   So it consists of num_rows arrays -each of which is an array of size = num_columns. Its equivalent representation using an array of pointers is-

   ```
   int* array_name[num_rows]
   ```

   -so the index given by [num_rows] still shows the number of 1-D arrays - somewhere using  malloc we can then specify the size of each of the 1-D arrays as num_columns. Is that right? I saw some texts telling

   ```
   int* array_name[num_columns]
   ```

   will the indices not get switched in this case ?
2. For a ID array I specify size dynamically as-

   ```
   int *p;
   p = (int*) malloc (size * sizeof(int))
   ```

   For 2 D arrays do I specify the size of entire 2-D array or of one 1-D array in malloc -

   ```
   int*p [row_count];
   p = (int*) malloc (row_count * column_count * sizeof(int))
   ```

   or

   ```
   p = (int*) malloc (column_count * sizeof(int))
   ```

   I think it should be the second since p is a pointer to a 1-D array and p+1 is a pointer to a 1-D array etc. Please clarify.
3. For ques 2 - what if p was defined as -
   `int **p;` rather than 
   `int * p[row_count]` 
   How will the malloc be used then? I think it should be -

   ```
   p = (int*) malloc (row_count * column_count * sizeof(int))
   ```

Please correct, confirm, improve.

Comment: Language tag and code formatting please

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47235897/841108) answer

Comment: The core problem is that the two forms are _not_ equivalent. Possible duplicate of [Correctly allocating multi-dimensional arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays).

Answer (score 2):

Declaring :

```
int *array_name[num_rows];
```

or :

```
int *array_name[num_columns];
```

is the same thing. Only the name changes, but your variable is still referring to rows because C is a [row major](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order) so you should name it row.

Here is how to allocate a 2D array :

```
int (*p)[column] = malloc (sizeof(int[row][column]);
```

An int ** can be allocated whereas int [][] is a temporary array defined only in the scope of your function.

Don't forget that a semicolon is needed at the end of nearly every line.
You should read [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays) for a more complete explanation of the subject

Comment: No, to allocate a 2D array you would allocate it using a _pointer_ not an array. In you example `p` is already an allocated array. To allocate it dynamically, use `int (*p)[column] = malloc (sizeof(int[row][column]);`. Alternatively, you could make a look-up table thing with a `int** p` but that's bad practice in this case. See [Correctly allocating multi-dimensional arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays).

Comment: @Lundin I see where I was wrong and believe to have made the necessary corrections as so misconception should not spread thanks for pointing out the errors. Please tell me if I am correct now.

Answer (score 1):

1. (and 2.)

   > If I have a 2-D array
   >
   > `int array_name[num_rows][num_columns];`
   >
   > So it consists of num_rows arrays -each of which is an array of size = num_columns.

If both `num_rows` and `num_columns` are known at compile time, that line declares an array of `num_rows` arrays of `num_columns` `int`s, which, yes, is commonly referred as a 2D array of `int`.

Since C99 (and optionally in C11) you can use two variables unknown at compile time and end up declaring a Variable-Length Array, instead.

> Its equivalent representation using an array of pointers is
>
> `int* array_name[num_rows];`
>
> So the index given by [num_rows] still shows the number of 1-D arrays - somewhere using malloc we can then specify the size of each of the 1-D arrays as num_columns. Is that right?

Technically, now `array_name` is declared as an **array of** `num_rows` **pointers** to `int`, not arrays. To "complete" the "2D array", one should traverse the array and allocate memory for each row. Note that the rows could have different sizes.

Using this form:

```
int (*array_name)[num_columns];
//  ^           ^ note the parenthesis 
array_name = malloc(num_rows * sizeof *array_name);
```

Here, `array_name` is declared as a **pointer to an array** of `num_columns` `int`s and then the desired number of rows is allocated.

3.

> what if p was defined as `int **p;`

The other answers show how to allocate memory in this case, but while it is widely used, it isn't always the best solution. See e.g.:

[Correctly allocating multi-dimensional arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays)

Comment: Note that at least the two most-upvoted answers posted to [How do we allocate a 2-D array using One malloc statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8740195/how-do-we-allocate-a-2-d-array-using-one-malloc-statement) are not guaranteed to work because they don't guarantee suitable alignment of the data elements.  This is much better:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays

Comment: @AndrewHenle Good point, I should search for a better dupe. I liked the answers by [chux](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48909970/4944425) and [John Bode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8742251/4944425), though.