# How to free() the memory which is referenced by **pointer?

Tags: c

Please help me understand this:

1. I have a pointer to a pointer

   ```
   char** word_array = NULL;
   ```
2. Then I dynamically allocate memory in my code:

   ```
   n = 6;
   word_array = (char *) malloc(n* sizeof(char*));
   ```
3. How do I delete all the memory allocated for the "array" of pointers? Is this call to `free` right?

   ```
   free(word_array);
   ```

   Or should I make a loop:

   ```
   for(int i = 0 ; i < n; i++) free(word_array + i);
   ```

Comment: Take a glance, for it may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53659983/3808573

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You used one `malloc`, so you should use one `free`.

Also the cast to `char*` is nonsense: `word_array` has type `char**`, not `char*`, and casting result of `malloc()` is [discouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

So the entire flow will be like this:

```
int n;

char** word_array = NULL;

n = 6;
word_array = malloc(n* sizeof(char*));

if (word_array == NULL) {
    /* handle allocation error */
} else {
    /* do some work with word_array */

    /* free pointers stored in word_array if they are dynamically allocated
       and not freed yet */

    free(word_array);
}
```

Comment: And even better: `sizeof(*word_array)`

Comment: And *even better*: don’t declare `word_array` (or `n`) before assigning to it.

Comment: @MikeCAT Thanks for the reply! yes, I wasn't intending to add the casting, Thanks for mentioning it as well!

Comment: @PETROSCHOOL Sorry, but I really have to ask you you did a cast without intention? :D

Comment: @klutt yes, and it's unnecessary here

Comment: @PETROSCHOOL Yes, I'm just asking how you managed to add it by accident.